# MySql NOT IN query gives wrong results

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a simple database that I want to use to do some data analysis. My original data was in excel documents so, I exported them as csv file with character encoding UTF-8. I used mysqlimport to import them into mysql to populate my tables. I have two tables one alice_db and other total_stock. Mysql table collations are utf8_general_ci.

[image]

[image]

What I want is a simple query. I want to find barcodes in alice_db that are not in total_stock.

I used the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `alice_db` WHERE barcode not in (select barcode from total_stock);
```

I also tried NOT EXISTS with same results.

But I always get the result as all barcodes in alice_db are not in total_stock. However a manual observation there are barcodes in alice_db that are not in total_stock.

my mysql version is mysql5.7.31.

I spent lot of time on this problem but couldn't find a proper answer. I think the problem is comparing the two columns is some how always results as mismatch even when value are similar. Please help me with this one.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: Can `barcode` be `NULL`?

Comment: in alice_db table barcode can be NULL but in total_stock table carcode is not NULL

Comment: Show `SHOW CREATE TABLE total_stock;` output. Does `barcode` have explicit NOT NULL option? The problem claims that this column is NOT defined as NOT NULL and it does contain NULL value. Test ```SELECT * FROM `alice_db` WHERE barcode not in (select barcode from total_stock WHERE barcode IS NOT NULL);``` - it should produce correct output.

Comment: You say "are not in total_stock" both times -- please correct.

Comment: What was the output from your sample data?  And what should it have been?  (Suggest you change from `SELECT *` to `SELECT barcode`.)

Comment: @akina Thankx for your helpful comment but I tried the IS NOT NULL in subquery still the same reult

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables and INSERT INTo with some sample data which allows to reproduce your issue. or create online fiddle (for example, on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7)

Comment: @Rick James Thank you. I tried only querying barcode from alice_db but still same result. "are not in total stock"- I want to find barcodes that only exists in alice_db not total_stock. Actually what I want is to find missing books after doing a stock taking.

Comment: my guess is its something to do with encoding since I am importing data from csv files. Does anyone have an Idea regarding this. Thanx

Comment: As already asked, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE alice_db;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE total_stock;` and add the output (as text) into the question.

Comment: If the text is all English, the charset or collation is unlikely to have any impact.